# Html css with jsfiddle ex: not working: vertical align and using full width based on width percentage of two child containers

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lthpf72/5/

Html css with jsfiddle ex: not working: vertical align and using full width based on width percentage of two child containers

When I make the two child containers add up to the parent width percentage, it folds down. Also the vertical align middle is at the bottom, not the middle.

Any thoughts?

```css
.payee.list-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
}
.list-item-content {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 80%
}
.payee.list-item>img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="payee list-item">
  <img src="/Image/PayeeBillPayAccountPortrait/832">
  <div class="list-item-content">
    <h4>Colonel Sanders!</h4>
    <h3>Colonel Sanders</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like that?

```css
.payee.list-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.list-item-content {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 80%
}
h3, h4 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px;
  }

h3{background: lightgray;}
h4{background: gray;}

.payee.list-item>img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-height: 45px;
  width: 17%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="payee list-item">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/6555/nature-sunset-person-woman.jpg">
  <div class="list-item-content">
    <h3>Colonel Sanders</h3>
    <h4>Colonel Sanders!</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I want the image to be centered, and the 20% and 80% widths to not overlap and equal 100%

Comment: do you mean something like that ?

Comment: I was on mobile earlier and neglected to mention that I wanted to use inline-block and not floats.

Comment: Also, no position: absolute.

Comment: I think vertical-align needs the parent to have a line-height.  I think the two widths don't have to add up to 100%.  I was hoping not, but that looks like the case in the examples I have found.

Comment: well you can always add padding

Comment: no problem, would be nice if you upvote my answer if it helped you :)